# Configuring MySQL server to avoid "MySQL Server has gone away" error

Tags: mysql

When I tried to establish a MySQL database using a dump, I got the following error message

```
ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line 312: MySQL server has gone away
```

After extensive Googling (and searching in this forum), I found that I have to increase the `max_allowed_packet` in the `my.ini` file. I have tried various values (including very large values) for this parameter, but I cannot get rid of this error.

Even if I specify the --max_allowed-packet option in the command line (as follows) there is no use

```
C:\Users\Panora>mysql --user=root --password=root --max-allowed-packet=600M db < dump.sql
ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line 50973: MySQL server has gone away
```

I tried creating the dump file using the following command, still no use

```
mysqldump --opt --skip-extended-insert --max_allowed_packet=10M --user=root --password=root db > dump.sql
```

Please advice me what I am really missing.

Comment: This error message typically appears when you open a connection to a mysql database, leave it idle for a long time, and then try to use the connection again. Can you post some of your code or command line commands that produce this error?

Comment: http://www.webyog.com/blog/2009/08/10/mysql-server-has-gone-away-part-1-max_allowed_packet/ One more thing which you must have done- Did you re-start the server after increasing the max_allowed_packet in the my.ini file? ;-)

Comment: Check the error log for exact error description. "MySQL server has gone away" tells us nothing.

Comment: @sanmai When I try to look for logs in the Workbench, it displays that the error destination is set as FILE and therefore cannot display errors in the Workbench. When I look in the data directory I cannot see any log files created there. Where can I look for log files? (How to enable logging if not enabled yet?)

Comment: @Asaph The command that I used is similar to: mysql --user=root --password=root db < dump.sql

Comment: @Ashwin A Yes I restarted the server after editing the ini file.

Comment: this type of error typically appears, when you open a connection to a mysql database and leave it idle for a long time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After extensive analysis, I have found that the old technique simply works, yes, editing the my.ini configuration file.

But the actual problem is to locate the my.ini file (MySQL V5.5 on Windows Vista), which is in the following location and this folder is **HIDDEN** (not like earlier versions) by default:

```
C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\my.ini
```

(Note the name carefully, this is NOT Program Files but ProgramData)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not in linux, as I assume by: "C:\Users\Panora", you need to review your mysql.ini configuration. Did u think about the amount of memory to do a big dump? And did u try with the time-out of the operation?

And please review the configuration of the mysql service on windows, using start/run/ services.msc